# How to attach a file from Google Drive in a html form?

Tags: javascript, html, google-drive-api

I'm creating a job application form and I would like to have a way so the candidate can search and attach his/her resume from his/her Google Drive. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use google API which provides access to google drive.

Check the below one. [Google API link](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-js)